# Angular - same urls with different templates (ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a scenario, where many of the urls are accessible while logged in and out as well. I was thinking of having a parent state where I can handle the necessary resolving (getting user info if logged in, etc.) and all of the state would be a child of this root state. Then in the templates I can do `ng-if` for elements depending on user status. This is all good, except one thing: The API server sends `401` responds when the access token is invalid which causes the state not to load.

I would really like to solve this issue while keeping the HTTP responds.
Basic example:

Root state:

```
$stateProvider.state('base', {
        controller: 'BaseController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template: '<ui-view layout="row" flex />',
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
            me: function (userService) {
                return userService.me();
            }
        },
        data: {
            auth: false
        }
});
```

Home state:

```
    $stateProvider.state('base.home', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
        data: {
            auth: false
        }
    });
```

What I would like to do is even if `me` resolves to `401` still load the controller/template WHEN the `data.auth` is `false`. Otherwise I would just `$state.go('login')` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is UI-Router is getting the 401 response from your Ajax call, in which case it won't be able to resolve `me`, and doesn't load the state. You need to wrap your ajax call in another Promise, that way you can handle the 401, and still resolve the Promise, just resolve it with `null`.

```
$stateProvider.state('base', {
  controller: 'BaseController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  template: '<ui-view layout="row" flex />',
  abstract: true,
  resolve: {
    me: ['userService', function (userService) {
      return userService.me().catch(function(error) {
          //user is not logged in, but eat the error so
          //the state still loads, just with user = null
          return null;
      });          
    }]
  },
  data: {
    auth: false
  }
});
```

Comment: So basically whenever data.auth is false I should wrap the ajax calls in another promise. Is there a way to do that "globally" (my guess would be no)?

Comment: I edited the code above to remove the "Deferred Antipattern".  https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns.

Comment: I usually check the return value in the caught error, such that it only returns null if the server responded with HTTP 401, for instance.  I create a helper function called `nullWhen` that I pass to the catch block.  If the response code matches 401, it returns null, otherwise the promise is rejected as usual.  This allows other error codes like "500 server error" to be handled as usual.